# Как в jquery нарисовать модальное окно с highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть сайт. Назовем его site.ru Есть график highcharts он лежит на странице site.ru/adler.php
Мне нужно сделать кнопку, чтобы при нажатии на нее открывалось модальное окно с содержимым страницы site.ru/adler.php

На одной странице планируется несколько таких кнопок.
Заранее спасибо, с уважением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [jquery-ui.dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), чтобы открыть вашу страницу в iframe.

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 800
});

$('.dialogBtn').click(function(){
  var url = $(this).data('url');
  $('#dialog iframe').attr('src', url);   
  $('#dialog h1').text($(this).data('title')); 
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

```css
#myIframe{
  height: 780px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dialog">
    <h1></h1>
    <iframe src=""></iframe>
  </div>
  <button class="dialogBtn" 
    data-title="Адлер"
    data-url="https://aviareysi.ru/adler.php">Адлер</button>
  <button class="dialogBtn" 
    data-title="StackExchange"
    data-url="/">ruSO</button>
</body>
</html>
```

<sub>С вёрсткой особо не заморачивался, параметры отображения подберёте сами.</sub>

Comment: Спасибо, а какой id нужно менять чтобы применить уже к другим кнопкам?

Comment: Сделал 2 кнопочки, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: Что-то не получилось у меня.

Comment: https на jquery.ui напиши, Опять же - надо смотреть на ошибки в консоли

Comment: Ошибок в консоли вроде нет, а не работает

Comment: #myIframe нигде не обрабатывается вроде

Comment: Ну ты опять поместил скрипт над элементами DOM, которые нужны скрипту) Заверни тогда весь скрипт в `$(document).ready(function(){....})`

Comment: Опустил скрипт, но кнопки не реагируют

Comment: Обрати внимание, когда я добавлял вторую кнопку - скрипт немного изменился)

Comment: Заработало, спасибо огромное, а чтобы добавить графики к другим направлениям с другими мнопками мне нужно скопировать весь этот код, но изменить что в нем, чтобы не бралось значение с другого направления?

Comment: Просто в атрибуте `data-url` указываешь нужный URL и всё. `data-title` тоже отображается в заголовке попапа. Короче, копировать нужно только кнопки

Comment: Спасибо за большую работу

Comment: обнаружена проблема. При заходе с мобильного, при открытии модального окна сначала загружается adler.php  в модальном, а затем перескакивает в модальном на главную.